# Android toast on preference change

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, toast

I want to tell the user that when he has changed one or more fields in the preference window that it was succesfully changed but I am running into some problems:

```
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            // Implementation
              Toast.makeText(this,
                        "You have selected ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        };
        appPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

however I get the following error:

> The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is
>   not applicable for the arguments (new
>   SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){}, String, int)

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,
                    "You have selected ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You should use activity context as the first parameter